# Python PyQt5 cannot import name 'QWebView'

Tags: python, pyqt5

I keep getting this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'QWebView'
```

...for this bit of code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebPage
```

-I'm on a Mac running High Sierra 10.13.3
-I installed Python 3.6.4
-Installed PyQt5 (did this several times, including using HomeBrew)

I'm pretty sure everything is installed correctly cause when I run `python3 -m pip install PyQt5` it tells me `Requirement already satisfied`:

```
MacBook-Pro-3:~ ericj36$ python3 -m pip install PyQt5
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: sip<4.20,>=4.19.4 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from PyQt5)
```

The full error I get when I try to run my code is:

```
 ...line 4, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebView
ImportError: cannot import name 'QWebView'
```

So what could be happening here? What am I doing wrong?
(I'm new to Python - but not to development.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should just [read the web engine docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-module.html) before jumping to unwarranted conclusions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two different web toolkits for Qt5: QtWebKit based on WebKit and the newer `QtWebEngine` based on Chromium.

Your imports seem to mix up those two. `QWebPage` and `QWebView` are part of `QtWebKit`, not of `QtWebEngine`, which has `QWebEngineView` and `QWebEnginePage`.

So you can choose either

- [WebEngine](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-index.html):

  ```
  from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
  from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
  ```
- [WebKit](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qtwebkit-index.html):

  ```
  from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebPage
  from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebView
  ```

The interfaces of those two are largely compatible, but not exactly identical.

Comment: I went with the WebEngine option - works! Thank you!